# Can Dreamweaver respect the newline format of files?

Tags: dreamweaver

In a project we may have a CSS file which was originally created (and committed to our code repository) by a person using a Unix based operating system. So all lines in that file end with `\n`.

Whenever a person on Windows with Adobe Dreamweaver edits that file, even if the edit is just a single character, the newlines of the whole file are converted to Windows style, which is `\r\n`.

This is problematic because at the instant this happens a commit to the code repository will not be possible (will produce conflict) in case someone else (with a proper editor) has altered other parts of the file.

How can this be prevented? All text editors I know (Notepad++, TextPad, etc) respect the file format of a file. Can Dreamweaver do that as well?

Comment: I would recommend changing your code repository. It shouldn't be possible to check out any file more than once concurrently, so conflicts should not happen. [I think the question's off-topic and would probably be better asked in Webmasters or Superuser.]

Answer (score 2):

The only option I see is setting the **Line break type** in Dreamweaver to **LF (Unix)**:

[image]

I don't see any option to leave the line breaks as they are.